# How to store video tags into a database (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

In a video website every video can have more than 1 tag. I have a video table containing information about each video. How do I store tags? Can anyone show me how to insert and select the information about tags?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One design I can suggest is to create three tables: `VideoList`, `TagList`, `Video_Tag`. `VideoList` has many-to-many relationship with `tagList`. Their association is then listed on `Video_Tag` table.

```
CREATE TABLE VideoList
(
    ID INT,
    VideoName VARCHAR(150),
    -- other columns here,
    CONSTRAINT tb_pk PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE(VideoName)
);
```

I added `UNIQUE` constraint on column `VideoName` so that you will have unique values.

```
CREATE TABLE TagList
(
    ID INT,
    TagName VARCHAR(150),
    -- other columns here,
    CONSTRAINT tb2_pk PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    CONSTRAINT tb2_uq UNIQUE(TagName)
);
```

I also added `UNIQUE` constraint on column `TagName`.

```
CREATE TABLE  Video_Tag
(
    RecordID INT,
    VideoID INT,
    TagID INT
    CONSTRAINT tb3_pk PRIMARY KEY(RecordID),
    CONSTRAINT tb3_uq UNIQUE(VideoID, TagID),
    CONSTRAINT tb3_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (VideoID) REFERENCES VideoList(ID),
    CONSTRAINT tb3_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (TagD) REFERENCES TagList(ID)
);
```

Comment: What is RecordID exactly here?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your video table has one record per video, something like:

```
Video
----------
ID
Title
etc.
```

You would then create a separate table for tags, something like:

```
Tag
----------
ID
Title
```

And to associate the two, you're create an association table:

```
VideoTag
----------
VideoID
TagID
```

The columns in that table would just be foreign keys to the `Video` and `Tag` tables.  This intermediary table allows you to maintain a many-to-many relationship between the `Video` and `Tag` entities, since each video can have many tags and each tag can be on many videos.

Answer (score 1):

The most common approach is having 3 tables:

- `Videos`
- `Tags`
- `VideoTags`

Where VideoTags serves as association table, having basic set of columns: `VideoID`, `TagID`.